# Whats difference between test suite and test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Just installed fresh new react.

Create new `utils.js` file in `src` folder and write this function.

```
export const sum = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

In `App.test.js` I add this test.

```
test("test sum function", () => {
  expect(sum(4, 6)).toBe(10);
  expect(sum(4, 40)).toBe(44);
});
```

In `App.test.js` I have also this default testing code.

```
test("renders learn react link", () => {
  render(<App />);
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

When I run `npm t` jest show me

```
Test suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between test suites and tests? Why test suites show me 1 total, when I have 2 tests?

Comment: Test *suites* contain many tests. In this case `App.test.js` is the test suite.  That suite contains two tests, `"test sum function"` and `"renders learn react link"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test *suites* contain one or more tests. In this case `App.test.js` is the test suite.  That suite contains two tests, `"test sum function"` and `"renders learn react link"`. This means you have one test suite with 2 tests.